# Gantt Chart Graph Color Modifications

Tags: charts, colors, gantt

How do i change the colors to the graphs in the Gantt charge? I have 2007 version and it is a little vintage, but the person at work wouldn't help me, but asked me to join a group to find out how to.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?